# How to capture from ip camera using socket programming in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I want to get live video from Axis IP camera by c#. I want to use socket programming to get packets and deserialize them to get video. Is any way to do this?

Edit:
the video is in :

```
 http://root:pass@192.168.0.90/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi
```

and my codes is:

```
   Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork
    , SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);      
           sock.Connect("192.168.0.90", 80);

            if (sock.Connected)
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[256];

                int i = sock.Receive(bytes);
            }
```

But I can't recieve any thing.. Is any way to add username and password or complete address for addressing socket?

Comment: First, try finding the correct address. Point your browser at the given Ip and find the exact Url it uses to provide images. Using this simple approach, you probably only get single images, not a video stream, but thsts way easier to start with.

Comment: @PMF I am sure that ip is 192.168.0.90 and I have username and password for this. But I don't know how to adding user and password and I don't know correct port and I don't know how to get a picture. What's the scenario of codes for doing it?

Comment: Can you get a picture with your web browser? If so, copy the URL of the image there into your code. That's the address you need to use. The port will most likely be 80.

Comment: @PMF address of image of this camera is :'192.168.0.90/axis-cgi/mjpg/image.cgi' but I want use tcplistener function in my code and it need IP address ,not URL

Comment: Right, url doesn't work with TcpListener, but you could use `HttpWebRequest` instead. For using a bare protocol, you definitely need to consult the camera docs how to use it. Or you need to manually implement the Http protocol, which is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @PMF ok, I want to implement Http protocol manually.. I can work by HttpWebRequest or some libraries for capture video. But I want to use tcplistener to get packets of image from camera..

Comment: Then you first need to consult the manual of your camera to find out in which format it delivers the stream data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to reuse of open source libraries then habe a look at AForge.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AForge.NET

It handles a bunch of IP cameras.

---

If you don't want to use existing libraries you could convert an existing client from another language. Here is one written in javascript in nodejs. This client connects via a http client and saves the images to disk.

https://github.com/mjohnsullivan/axiscam

I don't believe it implements a httpclient or a filesystem writer from scratch as it is a complex exercise to get right.

Comment: No problem but the example you have given shows that you would need assistance in building such a codebase. AForge has already implemented it. If you are programming it to learn what to do then rather than reuse you should step through the aforge code and get an understanding of whether or not you need a http client or server, what protocol the camera uses when properly connected, etc. From that understanding it would be easier for you to choose which components you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Y'r a client for the camera so listener won't work as that is a "server".

You'll get an mjpg stream from cam = continous stream of jpg images.

To get the images out of the stream there is for example mjpg decoder on codeplex: <s>mjpeg.codeplex.com</s>

Edit 17 nov '23: link no longer exists

Comment: The link to `http://mjpeg.codeplex.com/` is broken, that website no longer exist.